# Почему удаляются строки из временной таблицы после commit?

Tags: sql, oracle

После коммита в данной таблице удаляются все строки которые я туда добавил. В чём проблема?

```
create global temporary table FXIP_BENCHMARKS_TMP
(
  fb_acct_id            NUMBER(18) not null,
)
on commit preserve rows;

-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table FXIP_BENCHMARKS_TMP add constraint PK_FXIP_BENCHMARK_TMP primary key (FB_ACCT_ID);

-- Grant/Revoke object privileges 
grant select on FXIP_BENCHMARKS_TMP to U1R2_RO;
```

Comment: Вы проверяете наличие строк в __той же сессии__ в которой вставляли строки?

Comment: Да, содержимое после инсерта есть в таблице до коммита

Comment: Т.е. если вы запустите `insert into FXIP_BENCHMARKS_TMP values(123); commit; select * from FXIP_BENCHMARKS_TMP;` подряд в одной DB сессии у вас возвращается 0 строк? `Connection pooling` у вас задействован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global temporary tables` позволяют "видеть" вставленные записи только тем БД сессиям, которые их вставляли. Т.е. если в сессии `A` было вставлено 10 строк и параллельно с этим в сессии `B` было вставлено 100 строк в ту же самую `Global Temporary Table`, то:

1. `select count(*) from table_name` - в сессии `A` покажет 10 записей
2. `select count(*) from table_name` - в сессии `B` покажет 100 записей
3. `select count(*) from table_name` - в сессии `C` покажет 0 записей

Похоже что вы читаете данные из таблицы в другой сессии, т.е. не в той в которой вставляли строки...

Можно проверить ID сессии сначала сразу после вставки и еще раз перед чтением и сравнить:

```
select sys_context('USERENV','SID')  from dual;
```

Comment: Да, так и есть, я не знал что новое окно в SQL/PL Developer создаёт новую сессию